# RWTValOrderedVector linking issue

Tags: c++

c++, migrating from Solaris Studio 12.3 to 12.4, RWTValOrderedVector linking problem

we are upgrading c++ compiler from Solaris studio 12.3 to 12.4
I am having an issue compiling one executable

below is the error which comes at the time of linking

```
Undefined symbol 
const     std::vector<RWCString>&RW_VBase<std::vector<RWCString>,RWTValOrderedVector<RWCString,std::allocator<RWCString> > >::std() const test.o
std::vector<RWCString>&RW_VBase<std::vector<RWCString>,RWTValOrderedVector<RWCString,std::allocator<RWCString> > >::std() test.o

ld: fatal:symbol referencing errors. No output written to testApp
```

Same code works with Solaris studio 12.3.

if I write this simple code in existing code, it fails with linking error with Studio 12.4
     #include 
     RWTValOrderedVector vec;
     vec.insert(22.0);

Any idea what can cause this?
 any help would be appreciated